# Please help to correct my code for Python basics: 'for' loop in a list and cumulative sum

Tags: python, loops

```
enter code here
"""Write a function that takes a list of numbers and returns the cumulative sum; that is, a new list where the ith element is the sum of the first i + 1 elements from the original list. For example, the cumulative sum of [1, 2, 3] is [1, 3, 6]."""

def list(l):
 new_l = []
 j = 0
 for i in l:
   for i in range(l.index(i)+1):   
    j += l[i]
   new_l.append(j)  # this for loop seems to accumulate twice
 return new_l

print list([1,2,3,4]) # [1,4,10,20] other than [1,3,4,10]
```

that's all. Thanks for answers to make it work by printing out [1,3,4,10]!

Comment: I think you mean `[1,3,6,10]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improving your solution, you don't need 2 for-loops here:

```
def lis(l):
 new_l = []
 j = 0
 for i in range(len(l)):
       j += l[i]
       new_l.append(j)
 return new_l

print lis([1,2,3,4])  #prints [1, 3, 6, 10]
```

It's better to use a generator function here:

```
def cumulative(lis):
    summ=0
    for x in lis:
       summ+=x
       yield summ
   ....:        

In [48]: list(cumulative([1,2,3]))
Out[48]: [1, 3, 6]
```

or in py3x use `itertools.accumulate`:

```
In [2]: from itertools import accumulate

In [3]: list(accumulate([1,2,3]))
Out[3]: [1, 3, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two loops.  Here's a straightforward procedural solution:

```
def running_sums(numbers):
  result = []
  total = 0
  for n in numbers:
    total = total + n
    result.append(total)
  return result
```

Comment: Don't use `sum` as a variable name.

Comment: Seems pretty harmless in a small snippet like this where you can see all uses at a glance and tell that it's not the library function, but fair enough.  Changed.

Answer (score 0):

`list` is a bad choice of name for your function as it shadows the builtin `list`. Your problem is that you are not resetting `j` to `0` for each new element. Using `l` as a variable name is also discouraged as it looks like `1` in some fonts

```
def do_list(l):
    new_l = []
    for i in l:
        j = 0            # <== move this line here
        for i in range(l.index(i)+1):   
            j += l[i]
       new_l.append(j)
     return new_l
```

Another way of looking at it, is to get rid of the inner loop, and just add the current item to it each time

```
def do_list(l):
    new_l = []
    j = 0           
    for i in l:
        j += i
        new_l.append(j)
    return new_l
```

Comment: amazing answer, though based on my not-so-brief code. Thank you!